# Bad memory allocation C++ for a vector

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, copy-constructor, matrix-multiplication

I get std_bad_alloc error in the following code. It seems the problems is when I add the matrix to the vector, the program crashes when I get to that line in the debugger. The problem is that only the first two matrices are read from the file, the other two aren't because the program crashes with the above error.

Comment: Try to remove as much as possible of the posted code while keeping the code crashing in the exact same way, might take you a couple of minutes but it'll make the people who might help you happier. Hard to get any kind of overview of that much code.

Comment: sure I just eliminated a lot of the code. my program crashes right after the second matrix is added to the vector

Comment: We still have no idea what `matrix` is.

Comment: And now the function definitions...though I already suspect problem with this scariness: `int **mx;`. Use `std::vector<int>`! There's no reason to manually manage that memory. (You probably have a bad copy-constructor and/or a bad assignment operator.)

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the copy constructor in the matrix.  When you insert it into the vector, it calls the matrix copy constructor and something bad happens.  Can you post the implementation of the matrix constructor and copy constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere in your copy constructor do you set numCols, numRows.

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer to the crash problem (which has been taken care of already anyway), but it should be noted that your assignment operator is needlessly wasteful as currently written:

```
matrix matrix::operator =(const matrix right)
```

The first issue is that it is taking the parameter by value. This of course means that when an assignment like `A = B` occurs, then a copy of `B` is made and used at the `right` parameter of the function. But in the current code that copy's only purpose would be to set the values of `A` and then be destroyed. You could just as well pass a `const matrix&` to avoid the copy. (Alternatively, you could leave the parameter as a by-value copy but implement whole operator as a [copy-and-swap](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap).)

The second issue is that this is returning a `matrix`. This could also result in a needless temporary copy being created. And even though the compiler might be able to optimize away the copy, there's no purpose for the return to be a by-value copy at all. The standard form of an assignment operator returns a reference to the object that was assigned to. So you should just go ahead and make that return type a `matrix&`

Comment: Good points, though re returning a matrix&: the issue's much more than whether an extra copy is needlessly made.  (x = y) should return a reference to x so that further operations are invoked on x, and not some copy thereof... crucial for mutating functions.  For example:  (yyyy = yyyymmdd).erase(4);